# My laptop screen has gone red even after I installed redshift and it's not going away

Tags: display, applications

Previously I had tried to install redshift to provide a reddish colour to the screen during the night, but when I tried to uninstall it using purge, it was not removed and so my screen is still red. Is there any way to remove the reddish colour of screen?

Answer (score 3):

Even though you've removed Redshift, it seems it has "permanently" altered your display settings. Try running:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --gamma 0.9:0.9:0.9
```

eDP-1 is the name of my monitor, yours may vary